# Having problem installing sqlite3@5.0.2 on NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sqlite, npm, node-pre-gyp

I am trying to install the most recent version of sqlite3 module to make tests of my database models. Note that I am using Ubuntu 21.04. But I am getting this error. Here is the log:

> 519 info run sqlite3@5.0.2 install node_modules/sqlite3 node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
> 520 info run sqlite3@5.0.2 install { code: 1, signal: null }
> 521 http fetch POST 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/advisories/bulk 496ms
> 522 timing auditReport:getReport Completed in 498ms
> 523 timing auditReport:init Completed in 0ms
> 524 timing reify:audit Completed in 499ms
> 525 timing reify:rollback:createSparse Completed in 86ms
> 526 timing reify:rollback:retireShallow Completed in 0ms
> 527 timing command:install Completed in 2791ms
> 528 verbose stack Error: command failed
> 528 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/promise-spawn/index.js:64:27)
> 528 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
> 528 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1048:16)
> 528 verbose stack     at Socket. (internal/child_process.js:439:11)
> 528 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
> 528 verbose stack     at Pipe. (net.js:673:12)
> 529 verbose pkgid sqlite3@5.0.2
> 530 verbose cwd /home/diesanromero/Code/platzi/platziverse/platsiverse-db
> 531 verbose Linux 5.11.0-16-generic
> 532 verbose argv "/snap/node/4150/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "--save-dev" "sqlite3"
> 533 verbose node v14.16.1
> 534 verbose npm  v7.11.2
> 535 error code 1
> 536 error path /home/diesanromero/Code/platzi/platziverse/platsiverse-db/node_modules/sqlite3
> 537 error command failed
> 538 error command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
> 539 verbose exit 1

From what I see this is an error generated by **node-pre-gyp**. I am using the latest version of NPM and NodeJS. I have tried other versions of SQLite3 like 4.1.1 or 5.0.0, but I am getting the same error. I reinstalled **node-pre-gyp** globally, and nothing happened. I already clean the npm cache, etc.

Anyone has an Idea what is going on?